# Fetching value of dynamic input type in angular 5

Tags: angular, dom

I am running with a problem in which I have a requirement to create dynamic row of inputs on click of `Add`. I bind my model with element using index and its all working fine.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
  <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
    <label for="grid-input-19">Service Name</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="Service-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="field.selectedService" #Service="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let service of serviceList" [selected]="service.Service == field.selectedService"
                  [ngValue]="service">
            {{service.Service}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="grid-input-18">Service Description</label>
          <textarea rows="1" name="Description-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="field.selectedService.Description" required
                    class="form-control" [readonly]="true"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 form-group">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" value="1" step="any" name="Quantity-{{i}}" id="daterange-5" [(ngModel)]="field.selectedService.Quantity" required
               maxlength="50" class="form-control" (blur)="onQuantityChange($event.target.value)">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" value="0" step="any" name="Price-{{i}}" id="daterange-5" [(ngModel)]="field.selectedService.Price" required
               maxlength="50" class="form-control" [readonly]="true">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question is on `Quantity` change I am calling a function which requires to modify prices. But quantity of every row input is changing all together. Suppose there are three rows of input. So on changing `Quantity` of first row input. All are deflecting together. What am I doing wrong.

```
onQuantityChange(quantity) {
    // How do I bind the value of row input price which is created dynamically on quantity change
    this.field.Price *= parseInt(quantity);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: the rows you are talking about, can you post code of table.

Comment: I already did and it is not a table these are div's created dynamically. There is a problem in binding I think so.

Comment: Can you share `onQuantityChange` method signature?

Comment: @ManojChalode I have added the code where I wants to set the value of price input created dynamically on `Quantity` change

Answer (score 1):

Try generating the id for the input quantity & price uniquely using the index value from ngFor like u did for name.

```
<input type="number" min="1" value="1" step="any" name="Quantity-{{i}}" id="quantity{{i}}">
<input type="number" min="1" value="1" step="any" name="price-{{i}}" id="price{{i}}">
```

Once you have a unique id, u will be able to recognize quantity & price using the event id.

```
onQuantityChange(quantity,event) {
    this.fieldID = event.target.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');  
              // output will be something like 0 for first quantity
              //then   get correcponding price element and multiply
    this.field.Price *= parseInt(quantity);  
}
```